# I am using Uncaught TypeError: owl.owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am using owlCarousel in my project.
I am getting **"Uncaught TypeError: owl.owlCarousel is not a function"** Error in console but carousel is working fine.  Here is the code.

```
 var owl = $("#owl-carousel");
if (owl.length > 0) {
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 4, //4 items above 1000px browser width
        itemsDesktop: [1000, 4], //4 items between 1000px and 901px
        itemsDesktopSmall: [900, 2], // 4 items betweem 900px and 601px
        itemsTablet: [600, 2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
        itemsMobile: [480, 1], // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
        pagination: false,
        scrollPerPage: false
    });
}
```

Included JS FILE:  src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"

Comment: I think the order of the two scripts(loaded one and yours) matters. try to check if the `js/owl.carousel.min.js` is loaded before your script because maybe it contains the function as function expression and not as function declaration! I am not sure, waiting here for someone to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: or check the correct name of the function. Maybe there is a typing error.Check the correct name by reading the dev version of the file or inspecting `document` or `window` in console

Answer (score 1):

Check your dev tools to see if the file is indeed loaded. If it is loaded - there might be some conflict of functions

Comment: The file is loading perfectly.

Comment: Try $(owl).owlCarousel ...  or to define it as var $owl and then call it $owl.owlCarousel.